# Using Jenkins, can the email notification include the job status of different jobs?

Tags: jenkins

In Jenkins, I have 3 jobs that I can run separately if needed

- `A`
- `B`
- `C`

I have another job that will run all 3 of these jobs, but 1 at a time. So it will run `A`, then `B`, and finally `C`.

- `XYZ`

I could put an email notification at the end of jobs `A`, `B`, and `C`, and I would get an email with the build status for each job. However, I would prefer not to have 3 emails. Is there a way to put an email notification at the end of `XYX`, that would send me the build status of `A`, `B`, and `C`? This is really only needed for failures. If `XYZ` fails, I would like the email to tell me which job(s) caused the failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create groovy script to get the all the job [A, B, C] details, build status etc,  and save this groovy script into the Jenkins severe email-templates folder. You could use this email template in your XYZ Jenkins job.